# Safe PHP script for removing empty directories only

Tags: php

I have around 2,000 sub directories on my web server created temporarily by users. Half of them are empty folders. 
Is there a safe PHP script to use RMDIR to scan and delete the directory if empty?

Comment: an easy one linner `find . -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;`

Comment: Be careful, it is only safe if you know those directories do not get reused.

Comment: Sure, will not be used anymore. I solved the issue for new users, but old users already created directories which are not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write your own function:

```
function rmdir_if_empty($dir)
{
    if(count(scandir("$dir/*")) == 2) // There are 2 hidden files . and ..
        unlink($dir)
}
```

Comment: If these directories are existing under a main directory (For example: MyFolder), will this function scan these directories as sub-directories? Would you please complete the script?

Comment: This script is complete for the request: A PHP function that will delete a directory only if it is empty. If you want to delete MyFolder, you call rmdir_if_empty('MyFolder');